# Delaying :hover using CSS?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a menu in which onHover apears a infobox, telling what the button does. How can I apply a delay so that the box apears let's say one second after i put my mouse over the button?

**HTML:**

```
<td class="info"><a id="login-edit_account" href="../login-edit_account.php">Edit account<span><div id="pointer"></div><p style="font-size:11px">Edit user's information.</p></span></a></td>
```

**CSS:**

```
td.info                     {
                            position:relative; /*this is the key*/
                            z-index:24; background-color:#ccc;
                            color:#000;
                            text-decoration:none
                            }

td.info:hover               {
                            z-index:25;
                            background-color:#fff
                            }

td.info span                {
                            display: none;
                            transition: 0s display;
                            }

td.info:hover span          { /*the span will display just on :hover state*/
                            display:block;
                            position:absolute;
                            top:42px; left:7px;
                            width:210px;
                            border:2px solid #0cf;
                            padding: 5px;
                            background-color:#fff; color:#000;
                            text-align: center;
                            -webkit-transition-delay:5s;
                            }

#pointer                    {
                            border:solid 10px transparent;
                            border-bottom-color:#0cf;
                            position:absolute;
                            margin:-27px 0px 0px 10px;
                            }
```

Answer (score 5):

It's really pretty simple. Example:

```
a {
    -webkit-transition: 1s 3s;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

When the user hovers the link, the browser waits 3 seconds. Only when those seconds have passed does the background transition to red (in this case with a 1s transition time).

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/VP7hE/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use CSS3's [transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) to delay the `:hover` effect.

> CSS transitions, which are part of the CSS3 set of specifications,
>   provide a way to control animation speed when changing CSS properties.
>   Instead of having property changes take effect immediately, you can
>   cause the changes in a property to take place over a period of time.
>   For example, if you change the color of an element from white to
>   black, usually the change is instantaneous. With CSS transitions
>   enabled, changes occur at time intervals that follow an acceleration
>   curve, all of which can be customized.

In your case I believe you need to focus on the [transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transition-delay) property.

Here are a few useful links in regard to using transitions/example use cases:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transition-delay

http://css-tricks.com/transition-delay-delays/

http://designshack.net/articles/css/create-stunning-effects-with-css-transition-delays/

Comment: thank you for your answer...i found this solution but it doesn't do anything

Comment: @AlesSvetina Which browser are you using? Did you try looking at the examples I linked to? It should work..

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I tried in IE and it also doesn't work

Comment: @AlesSvetina It doesn't work in IE but should in Chrome, did you look at the document I linked to you about -webkit-transition, -moz-transiton etc?

Comment: yes i did...I don't quite get it...i tried with -webkit-...i guess I'm trying to delay the display part of td.info?

Comment: @AlesSvetina I don't know which bit you are trying to delay, the td.info:hover or the td.info:hover span

Comment: the span...the appearance of the little pop-up info box

Comment: @AlesSvetina In that case change the CSS I did above accordingly to the correct selectors, and try the -webkit-transition too and it should work

Comment: not working :/ i'm new to this...i edited the css part of the code to what it looks like now

Comment: @AlesSvetina Can you create a quick jsFiddle using your html and css so I can see why? Your code doesn't seem to do anything on hover

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WGMV4/

Comment: does it work for you? It works for me...just not the delay part

Comment: @AlesSvetina Sadly I can't in this case - maybe try googling 'CSS transition delay' as there are many examples of it working, maybe you're missing something in the code (I haven't really used this feature myself, but have seen it used to do what you want to have)

Comment: w3 schools changed the link to `http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp` (removed the 3 on `/css/` and since its 1 character SO wont let me correct it :)

Comment: You can not do this, you will have to find a way around because "display" is not animatable, check the w3schools website and it will tell you